# How to Draw Financial Transactions Graph using MPAndroid Chart Library

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I'm Trying to create a Financial transactions Graph like banks ,As shown in this Pic
[image: This Image]

When Customer Selects the Start and End Date , Graph should show the Months on XAxis and Date and Amount when transaction was done as shown by White filled circle .
I have tried examples provided by library but I wasn't able to use string labels and plot real time values !

Comment: I think there are a lot of examples on the internet which can help you in all the charts those are available under MPAndroid chart library please do some research before posting question reference:-
 https://www.studytutorial.in/android-line-chart-or-line-graph-using-mpandroid-library-tutorial

Comment: I did my research before posting this Question , My question is different ! don't be so quick to judge

Comment: if you know how to populate a graph you can easily implement a `list` containing data within the date range and fill the view accordingly

Comment: Ok i have got it now , thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using IAxisValueFormatter

```
final String[] months = new String[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr" };

IAxisValueFormatter formatter = new IAxisValueFormatter() {

    @Override
    public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
        return months [(int) value];
    }

    @Override
    public int getDecimalDigits() {  return 0; }
};

XAxis xAxis = mLineChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
xAxis.setValueFormatter(formatter);
```

Comment: Thankyou ! Just one question ,  what if i want to show a transaction that happened on 20 jan with amount on lefAxis ?

Comment: Basically i want to Show Transactions that happened on different dates , there maybe many transactions on same day

Comment: SO i have arrange both in month !

Comment: I havent tried doing so, I suggest using bargraph for that.. I think it is too complex for line chart